# Увеличение размера или scale объекта влияет ли на производительность?

Tags: unity3d, производительность, коллизии

Создаю мобильную 2д игру "Тетрис с физикой", из-за чего нужны точные коллизии. Но как оказалось коллизии больше чем указываешь. После эксперементов пришел к выводу: проще увеличить размер камеры и объекты, чтобы дополнительное растояние коллизии было незначительным. Вопрос: как влияет размер объектов на производительность?